# Modal background scroll disable in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile

I have a modal appearing in my application. What I want is to disable the scroll behind the modal, when it's open.

Currently I use `overflow: hidden` on the **body** which is fine for chrome and android, but in safari and iOS was not enough, since it let me scroll behind the modal. So I added `position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;` which solves the problem but it creates another issue that makes my page "jump" to top when the modal opens. I have tried to apply a few solutions found here and on other sources but without any success. Any suggestions on how to stop the jump to top thing? Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean "safari and iOS is not enough"? I use modals that disable the scrolling of the background (entire body) and the scroll position of the background is preserved so when the modal is closed it's at the same position.

Comment: @marekful Overflow hidden on it's own is enough to disable the scrolling and not jump to top in Chrome and Android,but in iOS it requires to add position:fixed. Position fixed adds the jump to top bug in all devices though. My end game here is to disable background scrolling and eliminate the jump to top thing in all devices.

Comment: I cannot confirm this either. Is it not because you have a`<a href="#" ... ></a>` in the link that is clicked to activate the modal?

Comment: @marekful no. body with overflow hidden is fine except iOS. If I want to disable the body scroll in iOS I have to add position: fixed which creates the jump to top of my page when opening the modal.

Comment: Do not add any extra CSS to the body. Add a modal overlay element (as first in body) initially with `position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0, left: 0; display: none`. Render the actual modal content inside this overlay with `position: relative`. When modal is activated, change body CSS adding `overflow: hidden`, change overlay CSS `display: block`. When modal is deactivated, change body CSS `overflow: initial`, change overlay `display: none`. This way it doesn't jump in Safari iOS.

Comment: @marekful Does not work. I already have the overlay with what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple example. The initial document height exceeds that of the view port so one can scroll it down. Regardless of this vertical scroll position, when the modal is opened, the page doesn't jump, and when closed, the scroll position of the initial document is restored (not changed).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
    $(document.body).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('#overlay').show();
  });
  $('#overlay').click(function() {
    $(document.body).css('overflow', 'initial');
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay" style="position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4); display: none">
  <div style="width: auto; margin: 60px auto; max-width: 300px; border: 1px blue solid; position: relative; height: 1500px;">Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>Some content<br/>in the modal<br/>dialogue<br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px red solid; width: 200px; height: 1800px;">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="test">Click</a><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After not finding any solutions I just used **body-scroll-lock** npm package which works perfectly fine under any circumstance. Too bad I couldn't figure out a solution on my own but if anyone is having the same issue should check it out.

Comment: `body-scroll-lock` doesn't work on iOS 12.0.1 and later.